# efeito rollover CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, eventos-do-mouse

Estou tentando fazer um efeito  rollover  em CSS alguém poderia me informar se é possivel com HTML e CSS no modo que esta os codigos ? o efeito seria apenas adicionar uma borda preta em volta de cada item do menu . Obrigado pela atenção !!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo.png); 
 position:inherit;
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 border-bottom:none;
 margin:auto;

}

#logo {
 float:left;
 background:url(../imagens/logoc.png);
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 left:230px;
 width:541px;
 height:133px;
}
 
#fundoinicial {
 background-image:url(../imagens/fundoof.png);
 width:1024px;
 height:1080px;
 margin:auto;
 
}

#menufundo {
 background:url(../imagens/menu.png);
 position:relative;
 width:1024px;
 height:30px;
 margin:auto;
}


#ul li a{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 display: inline;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:0px;
 padding:10px;
    margin:5px 0 0 52px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 float:left;
 
 
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Alfatec</title>

<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(../PLANILHAS%20CAIO/projeto/imagens/fundo.jpg);
}
{
 
</style>
</head>


<body>

<div id="logo">
     </div>   <!--div final do logo-->
<div id="topo"></div>   <!--div final topo-->  
   
    
        <div id="menufundo">
  
  
  <nav id="ul">
         <ul>            
          <li><a href="#">Página Inicial   </a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Áreas de Cobertura</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
      </ul>
       </nav>
                    
</div>                
   <div id ="fundoinicial"></div> 


 
                    
                    
          
                   
                        
                 
                   
                        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código aparece quebrado aqui, mas imagino que você esteja querendo saber como fazer efeitos de hover.

É simples, basta mudar seu CSS com base no seletor `:hover`. No seu caso imagino que você deva querer algo assim:

```
#ul li a {
    /* seu código aqui */
    border: 1px solid black; /* Exemplo */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que voce quer um efeito Hover, certo? se sim, tente

```
#menu ul li:hover{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Sim , Muito Obrigado , só esta acontecendo um problema a borda fica preta só que cria uma caixa em volta do texto eu queria que esse efeito só acontecesse no texto , teria como ?

Comment: Consegui , usei                                                                                         
  #ul li a:hover {
 color:#000;
}